# Yii framework new column in database not showing in output of $model->getAttributes() method call?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, database-schema

Yii version 1.1.8

I have added a column to a table in a mysql database, 
but the new column is not showing in output of $model->getAttributes() method call

I deleted all files in protected/runtime folder, but still no column

config:  'schemaCachingDuration' => 0, // in seconds.  <1 means off

I can add data to the new column directly in the database.

Are there any other things that I can do to debug this?

index.php

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following line when in production mode
    //debug
        defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true );
        //show profiler
        defined('YII_DEBUG_SHOW_PROFILER') or define('YII_DEBUG_SHOW_PROFILER',true);
        //enable profiling
        defined('YII_DEBUG_PROFILING') or define('YII_DEBUG_PROFILING',true);
        //trace level
        defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',0);
        //execution time
        defined('YII_DEBUG_DISPLAY_TIME') or define('YII_DEBUG_DISPLAY_TIME',false);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

main.php

```
<?php
return CMap::mergeArray(array(
    'timeZone'=>'UTC',
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'catchAllRequest' => null, // null if online, array('site/offline') if offline,
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en_ca',
    'theme' => 'td',
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'preload' => array('log'),
    'import' => array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.extensions.*'
    ),
    'modules' => array(
    ),
    // application components
    'components' => array(
    'format' => array(
    ),
    'user' => array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        'autoRenewCookie' => true,
    ),
    'widgetFactory' => array(
        'enableSkin' => true,
    ),
    'urlManager' => array(
        ),
    ),
    'db' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'initSQLs'=>array("set time_zone='+00:00'"),
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        'enableParamLogging' => true, //show parameter values in log
//      'schemaCachingDuration' => 0, // in seconds.  <1 means off
        'enableProfiling' => YII_DEBUG_PROFILING, //show sql profile info in log
        'nullConversion' => true,
        //'initSQLs'=>array('set time_zone="+00:00"')
    ),
    'errorHandler' => array(
    ),
    'log' => array(
        'class' => 'CLogRouter',
        'routes' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels' => 'error, warning',
            'filter' => 'CLogFilter',
            'enabled' => !YII_DEBUG
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CPhpMailerLogRoute',
            'levels' => 'error',
            'emails' => 'neilmcguigan+tderror@gmail.com',
            'filter' => 'CLogFilter',
            'enabled' => false,
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CWebLogRoute', // show log messages on web pages
            'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
            'filter' => 'CLogFilter',
        //'showInFireBug' => false
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CProfileLogRoute',
            'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
            'showInFireBug' => false
        )
        ),
    ),
    'request' => array(

    ),
    'securityManager'=>array(

    )
    ),
    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params' => array(
    ),
), require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/override.php'));
```

Comment: I think you have to update your modal class too.

Comment: Are you certain you deleted all the files in the runtime folder - and that it is the runtime folder you are using? When I change my DB table - I have to delete a file called 'cache-1.1.8.db' Have you perhaps configured Yii to use a different runtime directory?

Comment: Yii is using protected/runtime i.e. application.log is created here

Comment: try removing schemaCachingDuration from your config file at all - it should not be required. If that doesnt work please post your index.php and main.php config file.

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with some of the options you are using in your main.php file, try removing all non essential options from the db entry, also what is in /override.php? As it is being merged and as the name suggests could be overriding whatever values are used here.

Comment: A database view needed to be updated to reflect the new column.

Comment: Thanks for your help Zack and Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just went through this problem -- I found out the new field names need to be in the attributeLabels function in the model

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'newfield' => 'New Field',
        ...
```

Be careful with using the "better still update overwrite your whole model" suggestion if you are like me and have a lot of custom code in your models.  As Sankalp Singha suggests, Just copy the "diff" (green part) from using gii and add the part from attributeLabels to your code.

Answer (score 1):

After you have added a new column in your table then just go to Gii and then click on model generator. In that put the name of your table again and then click preview. There would be an option of **diff** click on that and then copy the highlighted green code and copy paste it in your original modal or better still update overwrite your whole modal. Then check if you are able to get the values inside and are able to get the attributes. This should work.

Comment: This wont change the presence of the property in `getAttributes()`, you can create a new model and pass in the name of the table and still get the correct output - without ever using Gii. The issue here was due to the model being created as a representation of a view, not a table.